# перекомпиляция старых программ на фортране

Tags: fortran

У меня есть программы на Фортране, написанные приблизительно в 1993-1998г. Скомпилированы они были с помощью компилятора Fortran77. Сейчас пробую их перекомпилировать на Simply Fortran 3.2, чтобы работать с ними под Windows10. Получаю некоторые непонятные сообщения, напр., в операторе OPEN запись FORM='BINARY' компилятор считает ошибкой, исключая таким образом возможность обработки бинарных файлов. Как обойти эту проблему? Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: [GNU Fortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/) скомпилирует старый код.

Comment: "компилятор считает ошибкой" - какой ошибкой - нам надо самим догадаться?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не могу понять, как его скачать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Igor ошибка такая: Error: FORM specifier in OPEN statement at (1) has invalid value 'BINARY'

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries - ссылка же

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, старый код старому коду - рознь. Широко распространённое расширение поддерживаемое GFORTRAN немного иное: `open(file='big.dat',form='unformatted',access='sequential', convert='big_endian')`

Comment: Simply Fortran 3.2 - надстройка над GNU fortran, так что можно не скачивать, а пользоваться тем что уже есть. Если есть возможность правки кода, то прочесть документацию и заменить на `form='unformatted'`.

Comment: @Serge3leo, спасибо, ценная информация)

Comment: Да, если нет возможности или сил для правки кода, то, по-моему, Intel Fortran и PGI Fortran поддерживают нестандартное расширение `FORM = 'BINARY'`, возможно, и NAG Fortran тоже его поддерживает.